# let $P\neq R$ is a an ideal of a ring R.Show that is prime ideal if and only if $R$-$P$ is closed under multipication.

Tags: ring-theory

Let $P\neq R$ be a proper ideal of a ring $R$. Show that $P$ is a prime ideal if and only if $R\setminus P$ is closed under multiplication. it is an unsolved exercise. please someone give me a hint.

Comment: Hint: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: I am confused as to how De Morgan's laws apply to prime ideals...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Use the definition of ideal and write out what the set difference $R\setminus P$ looks like.

(1) Assume that $P$ is a prime ideal; show that the multiplication operation in $R\setminus P$ maps to $R\setminus P$.

(2) Assume that the multiplication operation in $R\setminus P$ maps to $R\setminus P$; show that $P$ must be a prime ideal.

For ideals and rings, write out the set operations to be absolutely clear about what is happening, e.g.,

$$R\setminus P=\{x:x\in R, x\notin P\}$$

Comment: thanks for the hint.I have done the the problem with this hint.